# Create a class in Angular and use it in a component to assign values

Tags: angular, typescript, class, components, angular-components

country-class.ts

```
export class CountryClass {
  name: string;
  states: string[];
  cities: string[];
}
```

This is the class that I created.
But now I am not able to use in another component.

This is the

component:home-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CountryClass} from '../country-class';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  countryString:CountryClass[] [
    { 'name' :"India",
    statename :['Odish','WestBengal'],
    cities:['Bhubaneswar','Kolkata'];}
  ]

  constructor(private country:CountryClass) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Facing error while using the property of class in this component.Maybe I am missing something.
Error that I'm getting is:

```
provide your error here
```

I am using angular after 1 year and forgot few of it's basics I guess, can't even find any proper answer to it.
It would be great if any one out there can help me out with this.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Also - have you copied this straight from your code? As there are a couple of formatting issues. Can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Comment: @KurtHamilton https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rmbsy

Comment: @KurtHamilton The app.component.ts has the code and check the model folder for the class.

Comment: @KurtHamilton stackBlitz dosen't show the error but my vscode does.

Comment: You're still not declaring your property correctly, and you're duplicating your class. I've updated your stackblitz and added some html. What do you want to do with it now?

Answer (score 0):

`constructor(private country: CountryClass) { }` If you pass something in constructor of your components it is a `dependency`. The injector resolves your dependencies, and it tries to resolve `CountryClass` which you didn't mark as injectable and didn't register as a provider. I think you just wanted to add a private field. Do it as usual, not from constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I removed it from constructor

Comment: @PrabhuDuttaMishra  Keep in mind that you can define class fields from constructor, but only for your custom classes and only when you manually create instances of those classes. For components, services, modules, pipes and etc, you can not do this. Because you don't create instances of components and services, the injector does it.

Answer (score 0):

make your CountryClass class as service class by adding

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CountryClass {
  name: string;
  states: string[];
  cities: string[];
}
```

Comment: I don't want to make it as a Service